# send data through WIFI and 3G in android

Tags: android

I would like to know if it possible to force my android application to send my data through wifi/3G.
also, is it possible to access my WIFI signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, when Android connects to WiFi, it disconnects from 3G. You can check [which network type is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784395/4538344) and decide whether to communicate or not.